# zend_parse_parameters should return zval from inside PHP_FUNCTION

Tags: php, php-extension

I noticed that in 95% of cases there is always just `return;` after evaluating `zend_parse_parameters` to `FAILURE` inside `PHP_FUNCTION`. It did not make sense because `PHP_FUNCTION` are expected to return `ZVAL`. I am not sure what default value of `return_value` is when it is not explicitly set.

I searched through all php sources and all extension sources that came bundled with php. In 95% of cases they simply used return.  In few extensions - `date` and `intl` they do `RETURN_FALSE`. In [an article](https://devzone.zend.com/317/extension-writing-part-ii-parameters-arrays-and-zvals/) written by Sara Colemon she used `RETURN_NULL()`.

I feel strongly that I should be using `RETURN_FALSE` for most cases which make more sense for `PHP_FUNCTION`s. Am I missing something somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If `zend_parse_parameters()` fails, it is customary to simply `return`. That is [documented in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.funcs.php):

> If zend_parse_parameters does not recieve what is specified by the Hacker as the correct arguments, and the arguments recieved cannot be converted to conform with type_spec an error will be raised, and by convention, the Hacker should `return` immediately.

[According to the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.funcs.php), the type of `return_value` defaults to `IS_NULL`:

> Pointer to a PHP variable that can be filled with the return value passed to the user. The default type is IS_NULL.

Furthermore, the [PHP manual notes](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.internal.php):

> If the parameters given to a function are not what it expects, such as passing an array where a string is expected, the return value of the function is undefined. In this case it will likely return NULL but this is just a convention, and cannot be relied upon.

So the actual return value in case of failing `zend_parse_parameters()` has to be regarded as implementation detail, and consequently, simply `return`ing appears to be most appropriate – just let the Zend engine decide about the default.